AirPods gestures not sending AVAudioApplication mute state notifications
I have a macOS Swift app that gets information from the user's microphone. I'm attempting to use the new (macOS 14+) APIs available on AVAudioApplication that allow the user to use gestures (pressing the stem) to mute the audio input.
According to WWDC, there are two "levels" of doing this: getting a notification and handling it at the app level, or using a lower-level CoreAudio API. I'm trying to do the former in this case.
Here's my example code (the relevant part is just Manager -- the rest is just a ton of boilerplate to get microphone input via CoreAudio so that this works as a minimal reproducible example).
class Manager: ObservableObject {
    private var controller: AudioInputController?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        cancellable = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: AVAudioApplication.inputMuteStateChangeNotification)
            .sink { notification in
                print("Notification", notification)
            }

        do {
            try AVAudioApplication.shared.setInputMuteStateChangeHandler { isMuted in
                print("Mute state", isMuted, Date())
                return true
            }
        } catch {
            assertionFailure()
            print("Error setting up handler", error)
        }

        controller = AudioInputController()!
        controller?.start()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var manager = Manager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func getDefaultAudioDeviceID() -> AudioDeviceID? {
    var deviceID = AudioDeviceID()
    var dataSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size)

    var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice,
        mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeInput,
        mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain
    )

    let status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(
        AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject),
        &propertyAddress,
        0,
        nil,
        &dataSize,
        &deviceID
    )

    guard status == noErr else {
        assertionFailure()
        return nil
    }

    return deviceID
}

private final class AudioInputController {
    private var auHAL: AudioComponentInstance?
    private var inputBufferList: UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer?
    private var sampleRate: Float = 0.0

    init?() {
        guard let audioDeviceID = getDefaultAudioDeviceID() else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }
        var osStatus: OSStatus = noErr

        // Create an AUHAL instance.
        var description = AudioComponentDescription(
            componentType: kAudioUnitType_Output,
            componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput,
            componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple,
            componentFlags: 0,
            componentFlagsMask: 0
        )
        guard let component = AudioComponentFindNext(nil, &description) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }

        osStatus = AudioComponentInstanceNew(component, &auHAL)

        guard osStatus == noErr, let auHAL else {
            return nil
        }

        // Enable the input bus, and disable the output bus.
        let kInputElement: UInt32 = 1
        let kOutputElement: UInt32 = 0
        var kInputData: UInt32 = 1
        var kOutputData: UInt32 = 0
        let ioDataSize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)

        osStatus = AudioUnitSetProperty(
            auHAL,
            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
            kAudioUnitScope_Input,
            kInputElement,
            &kInputData,
            ioDataSize
        )

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        osStatus = AudioUnitSetProperty(
            auHAL,
            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
            kAudioUnitScope_Output,
            kOutputElement,
            &kOutputData,
            ioDataSize
        )

        if osStatus != noErr {
            assertionFailure()
        }

        var inputDevice: AudioDeviceID = audioDeviceID
        let inputDeviceSize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size)

        osStatus = AudioUnitSetProperty(
            auHAL,
            AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice),
            AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
            0,
            &inputDevice,
            inputDeviceSize
        )

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        // Adopt the stream format.
        var deviceFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
        var desiredFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
        var ioFormatSize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.size)

        osStatus = AudioUnitGetProperty(
            auHAL,
            AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat),
            AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Input),
            kInputElement,
            &deviceFormat,
            &ioFormatSize
        )

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        osStatus = AudioUnitGetProperty(
            auHAL,
            AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat),
            AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Output),
            kInputElement,
            &desiredFormat,
            &ioFormatSize
        )

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        // Same sample rate, same number of channels.
        desiredFormat.mSampleRate = deviceFormat.mSampleRate
        desiredFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = deviceFormat.mChannelsPerFrame

        // Canonical audio format.
        desiredFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
        desiredFormat
            .mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved
        desiredFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1
        desiredFormat.mBytesPerFrame = UInt32(MemoryLayout<Float32>.size)
        desiredFormat.mBytesPerPacket = UInt32(MemoryLayout<Float32>.size)
        desiredFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * UInt32(MemoryLayout<Float32>.size)

        osStatus = AudioUnitSetProperty(
            auHAL,
            AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat),
            AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Output),
            kInputElement,
            &desiredFormat,
            UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.size)
        )

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        // Store the format information.
        sampleRate = Float(desiredFormat.mSampleRate)

        // Get the buffer frame size.
        var bufferSizeFrames: UInt32 = 0
        var bufferSizeFramesSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)

        osStatus = AudioUnitGetProperty(
            auHAL,
            AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSize),
            AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
            0,
            &bufferSizeFrames,
            &bufferSizeFramesSize
        )

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        let bufferSizeBytes: UInt32 = bufferSizeFrames * UInt32(MemoryLayout<Float32>.size)
        let channels: UInt32 = deviceFormat.mChannelsPerFrame

        inputBufferList = AudioBufferList.allocate(maximumBuffers: Int(channels))
        for i in 0 ..< Int(channels) {
            inputBufferList?[i] = AudioBuffer(
                mNumberChannels: channels,
                mDataByteSize: UInt32(bufferSizeBytes),
                mData: malloc(Int(bufferSizeBytes))
            )
        }

        var callbackStruct = AURenderCallbackStruct(
            inputProc: { (
                inRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
                ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
                inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                inBusNumber: UInt32,
                inNumberFrame: UInt32,
                _: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?
            ) -> OSStatus in

                let owner = Unmanaged<AudioInputController>.fromOpaque(inRefCon).takeUnretainedValue()
                owner.inputCallback(
                    ioActionFlags: ioActionFlags,
                    inTimeStamp: inTimeStamp,
                    inBusNumber: inBusNumber,
                    inNumberFrame: inNumberFrame
                )
                return noErr
            },
            inputProcRefCon: Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
        )

        osStatus = AudioUnitSetProperty(
            auHAL,
            AudioUnitPropertyID(kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback),
            AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
            0,
            &callbackStruct,
            UInt32(MemoryLayout<AURenderCallbackStruct>.size)
        )

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        osStatus = AudioUnitInitialize(auHAL)

        guard osStatus == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let auHAL {
            AudioOutputUnitStop(auHAL)
            AudioComponentInstanceDispose(auHAL)
        }
        if let inputBufferList {
            for buffer in inputBufferList {
                free(buffer.mData)
            }
        }
    }

    private func inputCallback(
        ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
        inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
        inBusNumber: UInt32,
        inNumberFrame: UInt32
    ) {
        guard let inputBufferList,
              let auHAL
        else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }

        let err = AudioUnitRender(
            auHAL,
            ioActionFlags,
            inTimeStamp,
            inBusNumber,
            inNumberFrame,
            inputBufferList.unsafeMutablePointer
        )
        guard err == noErr else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
    }

    func start() {
        guard let auHAL else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        let status: OSStatus = AudioOutputUnitStart(auHAL)
        if status != noErr {
            assertionFailure()
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        guard let auHAL else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        let status: OSStatus = AudioOutputUnitStop(auHAL)
        if status != noErr {}
    }
}

Note: if you attempt to run this, make sure to add Audio Input to the Capabilities of the app and the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key to the Info.plist
When I press the stem on my AirPods Pro (2nd generation), I get this:

How can I make sure that either the AVAudioApplication.inputMuteStateChangeNotification or AVAudioApplication.shared.setInputMuteStateChangeHandler actually get called when the stem is pressed?

Looks like the order of registering the notification is important here. inputMuteStateChangeNotification must be listened to after setInputMuteStateChangeHandler, which seems strange, because I would've assumed that the notification registration was basically an idempotent operation. The following change to Manager works:
class Manager: ObservableObject {
    private var controller: AudioInputController?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        do {
            try AVAudioApplication.shared.setInputMuteStateChangeHandler { isMuted in
                print("Mute state", isMuted, Date())
                return true
            }
        } catch {
            assertionFailure()
            print("Error setting up handler", error)
        }

        cancellable = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: AVAudioApplication.inputMuteStateChangeNotification)
        .sink { notification in
            print("Notification", notification)
        }
        
        controller = AudioInputController()!
        controller?.start()
    }
}

Thanks to Kuvonchbek Yakubov's answer for inspiring the idea that where the registration happens is important.

Your code is almost correct. It looks like if the notification is not registered properly, you get an error "Cannot Control Mic with Airpods Pro". Register AVAudioApplication.inputMuteStateChangeNotification in your ContentView and you can update the UI there. Here is the code:
import SwiftUI
import AVFAudio

struct ContentView: View {
    let pub = NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: AVAudioApplication.inputMuteStateChangeNotification)
    @StateObject private var manager = Manager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
        }
        .padding()
        .onReceive(pub, perform: { _ in
            print("received")
        })
        
    }
}


Thanks -- this put me on the right track. It looks like the notification has to be registered after setInputMuteStateChangeHandler.  Doing it the View doesn't make much sense here, as I need the notifications in the Manager, where I was already registering for that notification, but moving it to after setInputMuteStateChangeHandler worked.
